# How to regexp PHP looking for numbers in string

Tags: php, regex, string, split, preg-match-all

I've problem with regexp and I'm looking solutions for this problem.

I need to find in text numbers where is more than 3 digits, but I need to omit when number have on beginning/last **$** char.

**Example:**

*Lorem ipsum dolor **32** sit **32181527** amet, consectetur adipiscing **$18312.90**, **2432417$**.*

On results I want to get only this number **32181527**.

I know how to get numbers but I can't omit when is $ occurs.

```
[0-9]{3,}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [negative look-behind, negative look-ahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), you can limit match that is not preceded / followed by specific pattern:

```
$text = "Lorem ipsum dolor 32 sit 32181527 amet, consectetur adipiscing $18312.90, 2432417$.";
preg_match_all('/(?<![0-9$])[0-9]{3,}(?![0-9$])/', $text, $matches);
// match 3+ digits which is not preceded by digits/$.
// also the digits should not be followed by digits/$.
print_r($matches);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 32181527
        )

)
```